# Crash while installing Passenger 3.0.8 with Nginx 1.0.5 on CentOS 5.6 (with RVM and Ruby 1.9.2-290)

Tags: nginx, passenger, centos, rvm, ruby-1.9.2

After I downloaded the OpenSSL 1.0.0d and Nginx 1.0.5 sources, and after successfully installed RVM (v1.7.2) and Ruby 1.9.2-p290 on CentOS 5.6 i386, I did the following as root :

```
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

-> Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290

```
gem install passenger
```

-> Successfully installed fastthread-1.0.7, daemon_controller-0.2.6, rack-1.3.2 and passenger-3.0.8

```
passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Then it showed :

```
* GNU C++ compiler... found at /usr/bin/g++
* The 'make' tool... found at /usr/bin/make
* A download tool like 'wget' or 'curl'... found at /usr/bin/wget
* Ruby development headers... found
* OpenSSL support for Ruby... found
* RubyGems... found
* Rake... found at /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/rake
* rack... found
* Curl development headers with SSL support... found
* OpenSSL development headers... found
* Zlib development headers... found
```

Next,

- I choosed the customized installation (ie '2'),
- Entered the Nginx source path (ie, '/usr/src/nginx-1.0.5'),
- Entered '/opt/nginx' as the Nginx destination path,
- and entered the following extra arguments to *configure* : --with-openssl=/usr/src/openssl-1.0.0d --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module

Unfortunately, here is the problem :

```
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/rake nginx:clean nginx RELEASE=yes
rm -rf ext/common/libboost_oxt.a ext/common/libboost_oxt
rm -rf ext/common/libpassenger_common.a ext/common/libpassenger_common
rm -f agents/PassengerWatchdog agents/PassengerLoggingAgent
rm -rf agents/nginx/PassengerHelperAgent
mkdir -p ext/common/libboost_oxt
g++ -Iext  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<ext/hash_fun.h>" -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -o ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.o -c ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.cpp
mkdir -p ext/common/libboost_oxt
rm -rf ext/common/libboost_oxt.a
ar cru ext/common/libboost_oxt.a ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.o
ranlib ext/common/libboost_oxt.a
mkdir -p ext/common/libpassenger_common
g++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<ext/hash_fun.h>" -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -o ext/common/libpassenger_common/aggregate.o -c ext/common/libpassenger_common/aggregate.cpp
rm -rf ext/common/libpassenger_common.a
ar cru ext/common/libpassenger_common.a ext/common/libpassenger_common/aggregate.o
ranlib ext/common/libpassenger_common.a
mkdir -p agents/nginx
g++ ext/nginx/HelperAgent.cpp -o agents/nginx/PassengerHelperAgent -Iext -Iext/common -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<ext/hash_fun.h>" -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS  ext/common/libpassenger_common.a ext/common/libboost_oxt.a -lpthread -rdynamic 
In file included from ext/nginx/HelperAgent.cpp:63:
ext/common/Utils/Dechunker.h:232:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive
Connection closed.
```

I did not found anything on that. Have you got an idea ?
Thank you very much

Jacques-Yves

**PS: My procedure works on a Parallels Desktop CentOS 5.6 virtual machine (with a user interface), but not on my VPS hosted by Gandi (www.gandi.net)**

Comment: wait a minute: What i can see in what you posted is a warning. What do you mean by 'crashed' and where does 'Connection closed' come from?

Comment: This was made on a server through ssh. At the end of this, I was disconnected (ssh connection closed).

Comment: hm, to me it sounds like the disconnect has nothing to do with the warning. Did you try to reconnect and see if things are ok?

Comment: When I reconnect, nothing has been installed. In fact, the server is not used for the moment.